# adding a checkbox in a tab label in yui

Tags: javascript, yui, tabview

I want to have a checkbox in my tab label , but when i set it in label attribute the check box is added but when clicked it doesnt get checked , here's the code i used:

> ```
>    var tabView = new YAHOO.widget.TabView();
>
>    tabView.addTab( new YAHOO.widget.Tab({
>          label: "label1<input id='check' type='checkbox' name='check'  value=' '/>",     
>          active: true
>     }));
>  tabView.addTab( new YAHOO.widget.Tab({
>          label: "label2<input id='check2' type='checkbox' name='check2'  value=' '/>",     
>          active: false
>     }));
> ```

any hint to fix this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab labels are rendered inside link tags, so `e.preventDefault()` is used to stop the navigation to the specified URL.  See http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/tabview_js_tab.js.html#l17 and http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/tabview_js_tab.js.html#l97

You should be able to get around this by altering `myTabView.CONTENT_TEMPLATE` or overriding the `myTabView._onActivate` method before calling `myTabView.render()`.